# Typeahead Database method not working

Tags: php, autocomplete, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead, typeahead.js

here i try typeahead. its working in JavaScript . if i connect db its not working . pls find out what is wrong. there is any alternate method available to do this

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div style="margin: 50px 50px">
<label for="product_search">Product Search: </label>
<input id="product_search" type="text" data-provide="typeahead">
<label for="product_search">Name Search: </label>
<input id="namesearch" type="text" data-provide="typeahead">
<label for="product_search">Test Search: </label>
<input id="search" name="search" type="text" data-provide="typeahead">
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
// Workaround for bug in mouse item selection
$.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.blur = function() {
var that = this;
setTimeout(function () { that.hide() }, 250);
};

$('#product_search').typeahead({
source: function(query, process) {
return ["Deluxe Bicycle", "Super Deluxe Trampoline", "Super Duper Scooter"];
}
});

$('#search').typeahead({
    name: 'search',
    remote: '/search.php?query=%QUERY'
});

$('#namesearch').typeahead({
source: function(query, process) {
return ["Ravindran", "Aravinthan", "Dakshesh"];
}
});


})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my db search.php in the root folder

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db('test')) 
{
    exit;
}

$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$sql = 'SELECT id,title FROM games WHERE name LIKE "%'. $text . '%" LIMIT 5';

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $posts[] = array($row['id'] => $row['name']);
}
echo json_encode($posts);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing code syntax of 2 different versions of `typeahead`.

This one is for [Bootstrap-Typeahead](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead), which is part of Twitter Bootstrap project:

```
$('#product_search').typeahead({
    source: function(query, process) {
        return ["Deluxe Bicycle", "Super Deluxe Trampoline", "Super Duper Scooter"];
    }
});
```

And it is working since you've included the file `bootstrap-typeahead.js` in your code.

The other one is coded for [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), which also came from Twitter, but as an independent project:

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    name: 'search',
    remote: '/search.php?query=%QUERY'
});
```

And of course it isn't working since you don't include it in your project.

So choose one of them and migrate your code to only that version. Personally I would recommend using `typeahead.js`.

**EDIT:**

Since you are so experienced with this, I'm gonna help you a bit further.

First, you should include `typeahead.js` in your code and remove reference to `bootstrap-typeahead.js`.

Next, in your JS section, modify the code to use `typeahead.js` syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#product_search').typeahead({
        name: 'products',
        local: ["Deluxe Bicycle", "Super Deluxe Trampoline", "Super Duper Scooter"]
    });

    $('#namesearch').typeahead({
        name: 'name',
        local: ["Ravindran", "Aravinthan", "Dakshesh"]
    });

    $('#search').typeahead({
        name: 'search',
        remote: '/search.php?query=%QUERY'
    });

});
```

Your PHP code looks quite good but I wanna add:

```
$posts = array();
```

right before the `while` loop.

Otherwise I think you will be fine, and the rest will be your challenge (if there is any). Remember that the console is your friend.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Dear Sir thanks for your reply i include the file typeahead.js but is not working

Comment: Like I said, you have to eliminate one of them and migrate the code to that one syntax to make it work.

Comment: thanks. sir. now i remove the link file <script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script> and link the  file typeahead.js. but not working. my need is read from database and completed it. can i have the sample code for the worked one

Comment: Could you check the error in console first? You still have code for bootstrap-typeahead so i guess it would generate some errors.

Comment: if i use firebug its  not goto that function.i dont know how to solve it. i am  new for this filed